# PowerShell Prompts me for user and password after some processing time

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, office365, admin

I have this powershell that let me process two files to process distribution lists:

- A file that reads the distribution lists that needs cleanup, and log the removed files to  a log file.
- Read a membership file that have the emails to be added to each distribution list

The membership file has only two fields DistributionList, PrimarySmtpAddress.  PrimarySmtpAddress is the field of the mailbox that will be joined to the distribution list.

If I run my script it does the job, but at some point, after long processing, it asks again for the admin credentials.

I already have this credentials at the beginning of the script, creating a Persistent Session, and Importing the session with the -AllowClobber switch..

I'm getting this error during processing:

Processing a user@mydomain.com en la lista userlist@domain.com
Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (outlook.office365.com:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

If I put the admin credentials, it continues... What I might be doing wrong...

Comment: Do you have MFA enforced on the user you are trying to use for the process?, does the user also have all required permissions in O365?

Comment: Nope, the issue is that the script runs,  and after a while it prompts for the user and password even if it is a Persistent Connection, and I'm using my tenant domain user, so "Superman" rights are with my script...

Comment: Also the script is running with "administrator privileges" :(

Comment: My scripts is at these location:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARgkHbDbU5pqRUz239gzWaWcGLxrriu8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How long is "long"? `Microsoft.Exchange` sessions have a 15-minute idle timeout, you can see with `Get-PSSession -Name ExchangeOnline* | Select IdleTimeout`

Comment: Depends on timing... I started at 10am running the script.. I'm processing a CSV of 12875 accounts that will be joined to their respective distribution lists as the csv states..  at 11am I received the prompt. later at 2pm, 2:35pm, now at 4pm and 5pm.. the time interval doesn't match the Idle timeout... right now is running from the last time i gave the password for the credential of my admin user, and is still running..

Comment: Password requested again...  Message received: adding a account@mydomain.com.pa en la lista mylist@mydomain.com.pa
Creating a new session for implicit remoting of "Add-DistributionGroupMember" command...  The I/O message also appears before this lines

Comment: If a try  this:  #creates exchanges session using user credentials -I
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -IdleTimeout 2600000 i got that there is no IdleTimeout parameter, If I do  $Session.IdleTimeout = $pIdleTimeout, I got that is a readonly property.. what can I Do?

Comment: I modified my script adding $PSSessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeoutMSec $pIdleTimeout and in the New-PSSession added the $PSSession-Option, but still prompts me the user and password.